# Most of my Bootstrap 3.1.1 styling is not being applied

Tags: javascript, html, css, ruby-on-rails-4, twitter-bootstrap-3

I'm using Rails 4 and the `bootstrap-sass` gem.  I've been using it for a while, but I was having some trouble with a custom carousel and so I attempted to remove the `bootstrap-sass` gem and import the bootstrap css, javascript, and fonts manually.  That didn't solve my problem, so I removed those files and started using the gem again.

Now most of the styling that was working using the bootstrap css is now not working.  Buttons are no longer buttons, the nav is just an unordered list of links, one above the other.  However, a carousel is still behaving like a carousel.  It looks like bootstrap.css is being loaded on requested the page, but like I said, most of the styling is not working at all.  Can anyone think of why this may be and what I can do to fix it.  Please let me know what information I need to share to help you better understand what's going on.  Thanks!

If you use firefox or chrome to inspect components on the screen that should have styling that is obviously missing, the panels on the right that summarize the styling being applied points to specific lines in the bootstrap.css file, so it seems like the browser is under the impression that the styles are being loaded.

To help understand what I've got going on are all the places where I reference the bootstrap styling, javascript, etc.:

### Gemfile:

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'
ruby '2.0.0'
#ruby-gemset=railstutorial_rails_4_0

gem 'rails', '4.0.2'
gem 'bootstrap-sass', '~> 3.1.1'
gem 'bcrypt-ruby', '3.1.2'
gem 'faker', '1.1.2'
gem 'will_paginate', '3.0.4'
gem 'bootstrap-will_paginate', '0.0.9'
gem 'state_machine', '1.2.0'
gem 'pg', '0.15.1'

gem 'figaro'
gem 'jquery-turbolinks'

group :development, :test do
  gem 'rspec-rails', '2.13.1'
  gem 'guard-rspec', '2.5.0'
end

group :test do
  gem 'selenium-webdriver', '2.35.1'
  gem 'capybara', '2.1.0'
  gem 'factory_girl_rails', '4.2.1'
end

gem 'sass-rails', '4.0.1'
gem 'uglifier', '2.1.1'
gem 'coffee-rails', '4.0.1'
gem 'jquery-rails', '3.0.4'
gem 'turbolinks', '1.1.1'
gem 'jbuilder', '1.0.2'

group :doc do
  gem 'sdoc', '0.3.20', require: false
end

group :production do
  gem 'rails_12factor', '0.0.2'
end
```

### app/assets/javascripts/application.js:

```
//= require jquery
//= require jquery_ujs
//= require turbolinks
//= require bootstrap
//= require_tree .
```

### app/assets/stylesheets/application.css:

```
 *= require_self
 *= require_tree .
 *= require bootstrap.css
 */
```

### app/assets/stylesheets/custom.css.scss:

```
@import "bootstrap";
```

Comment: "Looks like" and "most of" is a bit vague. Your nav shown as an unordered list of links sounds like your css file is not loaded. Try viewing the source of the page in a browser, and click the css file to see if it loads correctly.

Comment: I should have been more clear.  I looked at the page source and couldn't find the specific style tag that included any bootstrap styling, but on the network tab, the bootstrap.css file is being requested without error.

Comment: And I meant most because colors are showing up fine, the `carousel`'s style and javascript is still "working", the glyphs are still showing, but buttons are no longer buttons, the `navbar` is messed up, the `hero-unit` is gone, my `label`s (the ones that look like pills) are no longer there, etc.

Comment: I can't help with rails unfortunately, but from a quick search it looks like you just apply class attributes as usual. Perhaps you used bootstrap version 2 earlier and installed version 3 now? In v2 it's called hero-unit, in v3 "jumbotron".

Comment: Maybe a stupid question but all you are talking about is the bootstrap css. Don't you need to include the js files as well? Have you done that?

Comment: I think I've done all I need to do that, but I am still very new at how these resources are used in a web application.  So I have added all the places where I reference bootstrap as a whole.  `Application.js` has a reference to the bootstrap javascript I believe.  Is this what you were asking about?

Answer (score 1):

Try updating your application.css to:

```
*= require_self
*= require bootstrap.css
*= require_tree .
*/
```

I believe order matters in a lot of these files...

Comment: Thank you for the answer.  As this question was asked more than 3 years ago, I'm going to go ahead and admit I don't even remember what project these snippets belong to anymore.  Hope this helps someone else though.

Comment: Haha for sure! Yea - I still like answering because you never know who may need it. Thanks!